# swift textView doesn`t show data when back to application while receiving bluetooth data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, bluetooth

I am designing a app to receive data from BLE device.
and there is a textView to show what the data the app received.

Everything is okay, but when I press the button on the corner left to second scene and then back to the first scene, the data doesn`t show on the textView anymore. But from debug area I could see the app is receiving data

here`s the part of code on showing data on TextView

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
        print("did update")
        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let stringFromData = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

            if stringFromData.rangeOfString("tem:") != nil {
                print("tem")
                print("Received: \(stringFromData)")
                textView.text = stringFromData
            } else if stringFromData.rangeOfString("gas:") != nil{
                print("gas reveived")
                print("Received: \(stringFromData)")
                textView.text = stringFromData
            } else {
                print("format wrong")
            }
        }
    }
```

here`s the shot images of the app

[before re-enter application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyPNy.png)

[after re-enter application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBsZy.png)

hope to get the answer, thank you

---

I found a possible solution to fix this problem.
I add an action to the button,

> ```
> @IBAction func onSettingButton(sender: UIButton) {
>     centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(discoveredPeripheral!)
>
> }
> ```

when I press button on the first scene, it will cancel BLE Connection, and when I back to the first scene, `viewDidLoad()` will initial bluetooth setting. therefore and the problem is solved.

But I still want to know why this case happen?

Comment: Are the text views connected properly with IBOutlets? Have you tried including the text view delegate in the view controller?

Comment: Yes, I have tried re-connect it. and What do you mean by include text view delegate? I am new in IOS.

Comment: I mean along with the viewController class have you added, ```class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ```? This makes the view controller the delegate for the texfield. Also make sure in the ```viewDidLoad()``` you set ```textField.delegate = self```

Comment: No, I have tried to add them. and it seems it worked. thank you!  but have you seen there is a button on the left down corner? it is a segue to another view scene. when I pressed it and then back to the first view scene. the textView showed nothing. Do you know how to fix it?